# Jsdom webscraping

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, jsdom

Sorry if it is too basic. I want to scrape a website which involves clicking links on page, and getting the resulting HTML. I read about the nodejs module called JSDOM which I suppose is built just for this purpose.

Can anyone please direct me in the right direction (blogs or some documentation) because I couldn't find anything worthwhile.

**Edit 1:**

 I have been using cheerio but it doesn't perform that functionality. I found these three links http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2013/01/15/web-scraping-with-node-css-selectors.html
http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/03/08/scraping-web-pages-with-jquery-nodejs-and-jsdom/

http://reustle.io/blog/simple-site-scraping-with-nodejs-and-jsdom

None of these links show how to actually use the JSDOM for JS manipulation on page and only deals with DOM manipulation.

Comment: The question is not too basic, however it will be downvoted because you show no research effort, and it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search would've given you what you needed but here's a good link regarding web scraping. You don't really need to use JSDOM, you can just use Cheerio (jQuery like syntax) to select HREF CSS elements.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs#commentform

Cheers.

Comment: This is valid for sites that do not have data that is displayed after Ajax calling, I have scrapped 7 sites like these, I am stuck on a couple of sites in which you have to click a few buttons for getting the required data. Hence JSDOM and clicking event to trigger the ajax methods on their pages...

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of interaction with the DOM (through Javascript or otherwise), you may run into issues with JSDOM not behaving enough like a browser.

You might have better luck with something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (which Node modules do [exist](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) for), which will provide a true headless browser environment.